# Second Monitor HDMI OK for Grub & boot but then no signal at login signal & after

Tags: multiple-monitors, ubuntu-gnome

I cant get my external monitor to work with Ubuntu-Gnome on my laptop:

When booting the second monitor shows the grub screen

On selecting Ubuntu-Gnome the UG icon with rotating blue circle appears on second monitor

When the login lock screen is reached the display switches to the laptop screen and the second monitor shows 'HDMI NO SIGNAL'

'Display' in Settings shows the second monitor as recognised and working

- ASUS monitor and ASUS X550LB Laptop
- Ubuntu-Gnome 16.04.2 (Although exactly same problem with dual boot Mint - but OK with dual boot windows 10)
- NVidia GeForce card - same problem with  NVidia driver or open source
  Noveau driver.
- Using Fn+F7 (screen off) or Fn+F8 (switch monitors) does not solve
  problem
- I have previously had this working with Xubuntu 16.04(.2?)